# PHP SOAP - Gives nonexistent [HTTP] Internal Server Error

Tags: php, soap

By documentation from here https://itorrents.org/automation.php

I have added their example torrent (Ubuntu x64 for testing) and added the code just like instructed:

**Example...**

```
<?php

ini_set( 'soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0' );

$client = new SoapClient('http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl');
$infoHash = $client->cacheTorrent(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://itorrents.org/torrent/B415C913643E5FF49FE37D304BBB5E6E11AD5101.torrent')));

echo $infoHash . "\n";
```

**PS:** Also, tested locally by downloading .torrent file and adding to the folder, same error. (Added direct link so those who test do not have to download it on their machine)

**Error log...**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in /var/www/htdocs/test/soap.php:6 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://itorren...', 'urn:xmethods-de...', 1, 0) #1 /var/www/htdocs/test/soap.php(6): SoapClient->__call('cacheTorrent', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/htdocs/test/soap.php on line 6
```